# html table: row 2 alters the length of row 1

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a tree with a three elements. Main Element, -> children, -> children.

I got pretty far, I can even collaps entire portions of the table. The problem however is, when I collabs row two.

At first, the table looks like this:

[image]

Which is fine. I have three `<td>` in one row.
However, if I show the second row (clicking on my blue arrow),
this is the result:

[image]

So, what happens is that the second `<tr>` then pushes the elements of the second `<td>` so much forward, that "SubKategorie_1 DELETE" has enough room to fit before "Hauptkategorie_1" begins, which is in a different table row.

I am pretty sure that all I need is a css attribute.

Ill give you the code shortend:

```
            <table class="mainTable">
                @{
                    var position = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.MainNodes.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        string catId = "CatId" + i.ToString();
                        string classToHideCatId = "classToHideCatId" + i.ToString();

                        <tr class="mainCatRow">
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/icons/icon-open.png")" id="@catId" class="buttonLayoutMain" />
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <div class="mainCat">
                                    @Model.MainNodes[i].name
                                </div>
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCat", "GlobalTagging", new { id = Model.MainNodes[i].Id})">Delete</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <!--subcategory-->
                        <tr class="tr2">
                            <td>
                                <div class="@classToHideCatId">
                                    <table class="subTable">
                                        ...
                                    </table>
                                </div>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </table>
```

With some basic CSS:

```
.MainDiv{
    padding: 20px;
}

.mainTable{
    background-color: green;
}

.mainCat {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.mainCatRow{
    background-color:orange;
}

.subCat {
    margin-left: 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.tr2{
    background-color:gray;
}

.subsubTable {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Question:

How can I make my table have differnt lenght rows?

Comment: At your second td, which has only one  ad cols=3.

Comment: sorry, what? this I dont understand

Comment: Change <tr class="tr2">
                            <td> to <tr class="tr2">
                            <td cols=3>

Comment: thank you. i achieved this by creating a table inside the table